# How do 'money back if your horse places' bets not lose the bookies' money?

Tags: probability

I'm one of those annual gamblers who bets only on Australia's biggest race, the Melbourne cup, so I know very little about gambling odds. Last year though several agencies had a deal in which you got your money back if you bet on a horse to win but it instead came second, third, or fourth. 
To the uninformed this seems like it'd high positive expected value: Imagine betting on a horse to win with odds of 3/1, for example, and odds to place (1-3) of 0.7/1 [so probability of placing 1-4 would be at least 65%]

If you bet a dollar
 1. 0.25 prob you win 3
 2. 0.4 prob you get money back
 3. 0.35 prob lose the dollar

Average expected value = 40%.
This seems wrong. How do they maintain their margin?

Comment: Just because they might lose with the odds you made up doesn't mean they'd lose with the odds they'd actually have. Generally the returns are such that the bookmaker still makes a profit every time (in some cases the additional money-back sweeteners might not be covered by odds but by other sources of revenue - are there any transaction costs that users bear, for example?). Do you have an *actual* set of odds for all of these?

Comment: The odds I used are for an actual horse. My understanding is that bookies on average make 10% margin by slightly distorting the odds in their favour, so the actual odds are always marginally less favourable than those offered. When this deal is offered though the odds for all the horses are the same as those of other bookies who are not offering the deal.

Comment: There are no other transaction costs for the user. Naturally their main sources of revenue are unaffected by this deal, which is limited to a few races a year and has a very low maximum bet limit.

Comment: Thanks. In that case they may even treat it as advertising costs or similar, defraying the costs over other races/betters. In the absence of actual figures this would be likely to devolve into a question about the actual business model, which would likely be off topic.

Comment: @Glen_b in Australia where the OP is from these occasional deals are pretty common and are just promotional to tempt people into gambling more. I got one recently which was deposit \$50 and get \$100 in bonus bets, I used the \$100 of bets to win \$70 (which normally would have been a \$30 loss) and withdrew \$100 and left the other \$20 in my betting account. But that's not they'd be hoping I would have done and I wouldn't expect to receive the same offer again.